# How to transform (move whole child dives) div to max width with css?

Tags: html, css

I have tried with these code. This is HTML code.

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="back_1"></div>
  <div id="back_2"></div>
</div>
```

Now I need to transform `back_1` and `back_2` `divs` max width of `body div`. I use like this. `transform:translate(100%)`, but it is not working. It doesn't transform max width of `body div`. How can I transform (move whole child dives) that divs ?

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. You need the two child divs to be of the same width as that of the container?

Comment: css transformation is an effect that lets an element change shape, size and position. what are you trying to achive using `transform:translate(100%)`

Comment: i need to move the child divs inside the parent div. @abhitalks

Comment: i need to move the child dives.. @AneeshA.E

Comment: @Harshana: Is this what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Ze9cu/1/ ?

Comment: yh thats i want to do.. thanks ...

Comment: @Harshana: I have now added that as an answer as I was earlier not clear of what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the clarification from you, it seems that you are trying to move the child divs within the parent upto the edge of the parent.

You started right with the `transform: translate(100%)`.

One problem is that you have to specify which axis you want it to transalte. x-axis in your case and hence it should be `translateX`.

The other problem is that the `100%` in `translate` is different from the usual percent units in CSS. The CSS percent units are dependent on the parent unit i.e. x% of parent's width/height etc. Whereas, the `translate(100%)` means 100% of the very element which is being translated.

So, in your case you have to carefully determine the parent width (the `.body` div) which should be in multiples of child's width. e.g. if parent is 100%, and child is 50%, then `translate(100%)` will translate the child by another 50% and hence reach the edge of the parent.

This will be more clear by this demo:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Ze9cu/1/***

*Relevant CSS*:

```
#body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
#back_2 {
    width: 25%;
}
#back_2:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300%);
}
```

Here, the child is 25% of its parent. So `translateX(100%)` will move it along the x-axis by only 25%. Making it `translateX(300%)` will make it move 3 times its own width.

Answer (score 2):

I have created 2 DIVs for better understanding.

**HTML**

```
<div id="body">
    <p>DEMO 1 (Flexible width)</p>
    <div id="back_1"></div>
    <div id="back_2"></div>
</div>

<div id="body1">
    <p>DEMO 2 (fixed width of parent DIV)</p>
    <div id="back_11"></div>
    <div id="back_21"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{ color: #fff; }

#body {
    width: auto;
    background: red;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
#back_1, #back_2 {
    background: yellow;
    width: inherit;
    height: 50px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
}

#body1 {
    width: 300px;
    background: green;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#back_11{ margin-bottom: 10px; }
#back_11, #back_21 {
    background: grey;
    width: inherit;
    height: 50px;
}
```

DEMO: [**SEE IN ACTION**](http://jsfiddle.net/kutec/VpXVL/)

DEMO1: [**Added On Hover**](http://jsfiddle.net/kutec/VpXVL/1/) for #body DIV's first DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Your view study this address

```
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp
```

example

```
 <style>

 #body{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:500px;
 }


  #body div{
        background-color: blue;
        width: 500px;
       height: 40px;
       /*General*/
        transform:translate(200px, 0px);
        /*Firefox*/
       -moz-transform:translate(200px, 0px);
      /*Microsoft Internet Explorer*/
      -ms-transform:translate(200px, 0px);
        /*Chrome, Safari*/
       -webkit-transform:translate(200px, 0px);
      /*Opera*/
      -o-transform:translate(200px, 0px);
        border:1px soldi red;
       transition:all 0.5s linear;
      float:left;
       margin:5px;
      padding:10px;

   }
    #body:hover div{
        /*General*/
     transform:translate(100px, 50px);
   /*Firefox*/
    -moz-transform:translate(100px, 50px);
    /*Microsoft Internet Explorer*/
    -ms-transform:translate(100px, 50px);
   /*Chrome, Safari*/
    -webkit-transform:translate(100px, 50px);
    /*Opera*/
    -o-transform:translate(100px, 50px);
     transition:all 0.5s linear;
     margin:80px;
    padding:80px;
   }

 </style>

 <body>

   <div id="body" >
      <div id="back1"></div>
      <div id="back2"></div>
   </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get you started as an example:

```
<style>
        #body
        {
            background: gray;
            width: 400px;
        }

        #back_1, #back_2
        {
            background: red;
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
            -moz-transition: .5s;
            -webkit-transition: .5s;
            -ms-transition: .5s;
            -o-transition: .5s;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #back_1:hover, #back_2:hover
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="body">
        <div id="back_1">Back1</div>
        <div id="back_2">Back2</div>
    </div>
```

EDIT::: Using jQuery and jQueryUI

```
<style>
    #body
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        background: gray;
        height: 100px;
        max-width: 400px;
    }

    #back_1
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        background: red;
        height: 10px;
        left: 0px;
    }   
</style>

<script src="jquery.js"></script> <!-- Your jQuery reference -->
<script src="jqueryUI.js"></script> <!-- Your jQuery UI reference -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#body").mouseover(function() {
            var maxWidth = $("#body").css("max-width");
            $("#back_1").animate({ left: maxWidth });
        });

        $("#body").mouseleave(function() {
            $("#back_1").animate({ left: 0 });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="body">
    <div id="back_1"></div>
    <div id="back_2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you want to "move" them? can you explain a bit more?

Comment: i need to move them to max width of the parent div.

Comment: so in this example, do you also want to move the position/location of the inner divs? or only their width?

Comment: with position.. not the width. whole child dives need to move to parent's max width

Comment: is the width of the parent at it's max-width, or is it less than? because you cannot go to the max width like that, you can only play around with the inner divs based on the current parent css properties. you can, however, use jquery/javascript to do that. with jquery/javascript, you can get the value of your max-width css property easily, and just do it with jquery/javascript?

Comment: @Harshana - Please see my edited post. Using jQuery and jQuerUI to achieve what you want.